# MSP-EXP430G2ET cannot pass code to the microcontroller

Tags: msp430

I am looking for expert help regarding loading a program to the MSP430.
I've tried:
https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/msp430/
as well as about 6 different youtube videos regarding this having me download different packages that should all work.
My disconnect is taking place here I believe, and I am not sure how to fix it.

[image]

On every video I watch MSP430 shows up as 1Com but upon plugging it in not only is it not named, but it is taking place on both 5 and 6.

I've attempted to pass instructions through either with no success.  The last times I used this method it just simply worked, but that was on a different pc.

Anyone have any ideas?  When using visual studios and when I get to the point of needing to select the device (like i did in the past) it simply acts like it isn't recognized and not apart of the system.

I have functional code I just need to be able to pass it to the microcontroller.

Comment: As shown in the LaunchPad manual, one COM port is for talking to the eZ-FET CPU, and one for the backchannel UART. Anyway, what software are you using?

Comment: I've tried visual studios with VisualGDB-5.4r12-trial.msi, VNC-Viewer-6.20.529-Windows.exe, energia-1.8.10E23-windows.zip.
No matter what I do/use I cant get it to receive code.

While using Energia I could specify the COM5 or COM6 and neither would permit the code to pass.

The only thing that has worked to cause a reaction was using VisualGDB, but it could only do the basic ledblink built in program.  Any action I tried after that even editing the built in file threw a :2000: "something about actively refusing connection or code"